# Twitter getMentionTimeLine

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

how to use time/count in twitter getmentiontime line

I am able to get time line of user but now 
**I want to get mention time line of last 30 minutes.**

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
List<Status> statuses = twitter.getMentionsTimeline();
System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s mentions.");
```

Please suggest me what changes I need to have.

Comment: What does twitter.getMentionsTimeline() method returns?

Some objects that would have the timestamp of said mention in the object? If so, you could loop those objects and only display the ones you wanted.

Comment: Seems that method would return Status-objects, so you could check status.getCreatedAt() and limit that to last 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks ahaaman for the reply, I found out the way and I have attached the code below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Paging`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Paging.html) object's `max_id` parameter to step back through the timeline you are processing:

> **max_id**
>
> Returns results with an ID less than (that is, older than) or equal to the specified ID.

For instance, choose a reasonable number of statuses to fetch (the maximum is 200 at a time for mentions), e.g.:

```
Paging paging = new Paging();
paging.count(100);
```

Fetch the mentions:

```
final List<Status> statuses = twitter.getMentions(paging);
```

Then record the `id` of the earliest `Status` and then use that `id` for the `max_id` attribute of the next call:

```
paging.maxId(id - 1); // subtract one to make max_id exclusive
final List<Status> statuses = twitter.getMentions(paging);
```

And so on until you hit your thirty minute threshold.

For more information, see Twitter's documentation on [Working with Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines). Additionally, be aware that you could hit rate limiting with this API call.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the reply and I found out another way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way by using getCreatedAt for status, get the status upto last 30 minutes as you needed in loop and then put break from that.

```
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getMentionsTimeline();
        System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName()
                + "'s mentions.");
        for (Status status : statuses) {

            // setting 30 min from now to date
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(new java.util.Date());
            c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30);
            System.out.println(c.getTime());

            // setting created date of status to date
            Date createdDate = status.getCreatedAt();
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            now.setTime(createdDate);
            System.out.println(now.getTime());

            if (now.compareTo(c) == -1) {
                System.out.println(" in zero");
                break;
            }


                            // User is class with getter setter methods 
            user2 = User();
            user2.setUsername(status.getUser().getScreenName());
            user2.setMessage(status.getText());

            list.add(user2);
            System.out.println(status.getUser().getScreenName());
        }
```

I am able to get the mentionTimeLine for last 30 minutes using this code.